# Is it good practice to do initial work outside function in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm a beginner in Lua.

Currently, I designed my Lua environment to be like the following.

```
function setup() --called in the beginning
    --do something
end

function draw() --called every frame
    --do something
end

function exit() --called on exit
    --do something
end
```

I wonder if it is better to do the initial work outside of functions like the following.

```
--do something in the beginning

function draw() --called every frame
    --do something
end

function exit() --called on exit
    --do something
end
```

Although the second design is simpler and quicker to write, I wonder if it is a good practice to write initial stuffs outside functions.

Is there any difference between the 2 designs? Which one is more common in Lua?

Comment: Normally when you have a `setup` function, it's because the library needed to do some inialization before you can do your custom setup routine. In a graphics library, it may need to create the graphics context and stuff before you can set it up in `setup`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But what if the library doesn't need to do any initialization before the `setup` routine? (let's say it's already done before opening the Lua code) Is there any downside of doing the initial work outside of functions? (instead of `setup`)

Comment: You have set `setup`, `draw`, and `update` functions because you want to control when certain things (like drawing to a canvas) happen. If you don't care exactly when they happen, there's no need to force the user to put certain code in an a certain place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. It's not a question of "common"; it's a question of what is useful to you and your application.

Lua, being an embedded language, is governed by the application that owns it. Therefore, the way the above Lua scripts execute is dependent entirely on the behavior of that application.

In your first case, you have 4 distinct places where code is executed. Your application must at some point compile and execute this Lua script; that's the first time your Lua code gets called. Then, at some potentially later point, `setup` gets called.

Now, what happens in your application between these two points, between compile&execute, and the call to `setup`? Or perhaps a better question is this: what services does your application provide during `setup` which are not available during compile&execute?

For example, let's say that your application is providing rendering via Direct3D. And it exposes to Lua scripts the ability to load textures from disk into D3D. When the script is loaded and executed, has a D3D window been created yet? Does the script have some control over *how* that window gets created, being able to set the size, framebuffer format, or whatever? Or does that happen elsewhere?

If D3D hasn't been initialized when the script is being executed, then the script *cannot* call functions that load textures.

In such a scenario, your application would promise that `setup` would be called after D3D has been initialized, and thus it is appropriate to put that sort of initialization code there.

But maybe you use some external script or configuration file to determine how to set up D3D. So when you go to compile and execute the script, all of your interfaces are valid. In that case, it isn't really necessary to have `setup` as a distinct stage from simply compile&execute.

However, you now have to contend with an odd issue: what happens if there's a compile error? You went through the trouble of initializing a D3D window and everything, but the script can't even compile. That could be a potentially large amount of work to go through just to stop for a simple typo or other syntax failure.

So there is some justification for wanting to compile & execute the script before setting up the environment, just to do some basic sanity checks on it and ensure that the script and any modules it depends on can actually be loaded. That way, you're not doing a bunch of work just to found out that it was pointless.

How you balance these concerns is ultimately determined by what is most useful for yourself and your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.